# Conversion of row elements in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Problem :

```
                               df['bua']          
                      
                      0        Built-up Area 97 Sq Yards
                      1        Built-up Area 85 Sq Yards
                      2        Built-up Area 80 Sq Yards
                      3       Built-up Area 100 Sq Yards
                      4        Built-up Area 87 Sq Yards
                                          ...            
                      1832     Built-up Area 73 Sq Yards
                      1833     Built-up Area 80 Sq Yards
                      1834     Built-up Area 82 Sq Yards
                      1835    Built-up Area 1500 Sq Feet
                      1836     Built-up Area 66 Sq Yards
                      Name: bua, Length: 1837, dtype: object
```

I need to convert each of the above elements of the column 'bua' into square feet.
Also remove  the 'Built-up Area','Feet','Yards' at the end.

Output :

The output should look like

```
                                   df['bua']
                        
                          0        XX97         ^
                          1        XX85         |
                          2        XX80         | 
                          3        XX10         | # Values in sq-feet after conversion
                          4        XX87         | 
                                   ...          |   
                          1832     XX73         |
                          1833     XX80         | # Values in sq-feet after conversion
                          1834     XX82         |
                          1835     XX15         |
                          1836     XX66         V
                          Name: bua, Length: 1837, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "Built-up Area", use the string method of pandas series:

```
df['bua'] = df['bua'].str.replace('Built-up Area', '')
```

Next, you should convert from yards to feet, but only where, it has yards as a postfix. Again use the pandas str method to split the strings at 'sq ':

```
idx = df['bua'].str.split('sq ').str[-1] == 'Yards'
df.loc[idx, 'SquareFeet'] = df.loc[idx, 'bua'].str.split('sq ').str[0].astype(float) * 3
# Where the metric is in feet, just take the number
df.loc[~idx, 'SquareFeet'] = df.loc[~idx, 'bua'].str.split('sq ').str[0].astype(float)
```

Then you have a column called 'SquareFeet' with the requested data

Comment: This gives the output :

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1095     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
   1096         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
-> 1097         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1098 
   1099     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 97 Sq Yards'

Answer (score 0):

Use `df['bua']=df['bua'].replace(regex=True,to_replace="[^0-9]",value=' ')`to remove 'Built-up Area','Feet','Yards'.

Use   `df['bua'] = df['bua'].astype (float)`to convert string to float and then apply the following code

Use `df['Sq.Feet'] = df['bua'].apply(lambda x : x * 3)`to convert yards into sq.feet as 1 yard = 3 foot.

`.apply()` applies the particular function to every element in a particular column of a data frame. As I don't have an entire dataset, I'm unable to try these codes.

Comment: The  'Built-up Area','Feet','Yards'. were removes but the Column 'df['Sq.Feet']'

gives three times repeated values in the column example 97  97  97

Comment: Now, I have added the code `df['bua'] = df['bua'].astype (float)` to convert the str to float and then apply the next code, you will be getting a column named with 'Sq.Feet'.